# Modeling complex shape of a monitor backside

Tags: modeling

Right now I'm trying to model the backside of the casing of this monitor

[image]

I have tried a NURBS surface but didn't manage to get the desired result. Then I used a regular plane which was a bit better but I couldn't figure out how to make it look smooth and "fluid". Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show all the reference photos you are working with? Or do you have the actual monitor in front of you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the most efficient way but it can probably be made with regular box modeling and a subsurface modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, this looks good... i will try it!